# How to know what encryption algorithm a private key is protected with?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I want to print the algorithm used to protect a private key.
How do I do that with openssl?

Comment: Question may be more suitable for security.stackexchange.com. You can ask a mod to migrate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I simply had to open the file

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,...
```

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Likely just opened it in a text edit.  Most keys are not binary blobs.